# How to remove user from telegram channel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

I am using telethon for adding users in the telegram channel but how to remove or delete users from Particular telegram channels?

There is one function to `restrict user so they can’t see messages` using `EditBannedRequest` but I want to **remove or delete the user from Particular
telegram channel**.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the raw API requests at https://tl.telethon.dev/index.html

The request should be `DeleteContactsRequest` which can be found at https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/delete_contacts.html

Example

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(id=['username']))
    print(result.stringify())
```

Comment: HI there, Great answer. How do I specify the channel from which the user needs to be removed? Say a user is across 3 channels & I would want to remove the user form just 1 of them. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You must use Bot API for remove user from channel, and 'DeleteContactsRequest' command remove the user from your contact list only.